# Filter the populated data and then paginate in Mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Hello I am trying to populate the data and then trying to paginate that data.
Here is the example

**Schema A (Users)**

```
{
  name: 'Demo',
  postId: 'someObjectId',
}
```

**Schema B (Posts)**

```
{
  id: 'someObjectId',
  postName: 'Post 1',
  date: 'date of creation'
}
```

Here is my code

```
const users = UserModel.find({
  name: 'Demo'
}).populate({
   path: 'postId',
   select: 'date',
   match: {'postId.date' : {$lt: 'today'}}
}).page(pagination).limit(20)
```

Not getting the result needed. Can someone point out what's wrong?

**NOTE: I have just given the overview. Please don't take it as real code. I know I haven't written what we would write in javascript**

Answer (score 0):

A populate have following things:

```js
Post.find({})
.populate([
    // here array is for our memory. 
    // because may need to populate multiple things
    {
        path: 'user',
        select: 'name',
        model:'User',
        options: {
            sort:{ },
            skip: 5,
            limit : 10
        },
        match:{
            // filter result in case of multiple result in populate
            // may not useful in this case
        }
    }
]);
.exec((err, results)=>{
   console.log(err, results)
});
```